# How to use dependencies in sam local environment?

Tags: python, pandas, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I am able to run lambda function locally using sam local start-api. Thats work pretty fine for me. Now I want to use libraries such as pandas etc.but it giving me error:

```
Invalid lambda response received: Invalid API Gateway Response Keys: {'errorMessage', 'stackTrace', 'errorType'} in {'errorMessage': 
"Unable to import module 'read_pharma': No module named 'pandas'", 'errorType': 'Runtime.ImportModuleError', 'stackTrace': []}
```

Below is my code:

```
import boto3, json
import pandas as pd

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return{
          'statusCode': 200, 
          'message': 'Hello World'
}
```

I already tried creating a virtual environment, but no luck. How can I use dependencies here?

Here is my directory:

```
Backend-Directory
    organisation_manag
        abc.py
        xyz.py
    user_manag
        pqr.py
        ust.py
    requirements.txt
    template.yaml
```

Comment: Please give a minimal steps to reproduce your error.

Comment: what is your `CodeUri` for your functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created your sam app using `sam init`, there should be a `requirements.txt` file in the project. Once you put `pandas` in it, you can run

```
sam build
# or sam build --use-container

sam local....
```

The `sam build` will handle the installation of dependencies.

### Update

Since you updated your question description, it seems the question you had is how to share `requirements.txt` across two functions.

Assuming your original function handlers are `abc.handler` and `pqr.handler`

You can make your template like this:

```
FuncA:
  Properties:
    CodeUri: .
    Handler: organisation_manag.abc.handler

FuncB:
  Properties:
    CodeUri: .
    Handler: organisation_manag.pqr.handler
```

Comment: Yes, it works fine in the default directory. But my directory is different and it causing errors. I have edited my question and include my directory path.

Comment: how different is your directory?

Comment: I have put my directory path and when I run sam build, it asked requirements.txt file in each directory (organisation_manag, org_manag). How can I keep only one requirements.txt file and achieve the same?

Comment: not sure what that means, can you put an example in your question description?